# SQL | Servidor local MySQL Workbench con 2 computadoras

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector

en mi hogar tengo una computadora (PC #1) y otra (PC #2). En PC #1 desarrollo un programa en Java y administro la base de datos MySQL con Workbench, ahora quiero realizar consultas desde PC #2 con el mismo programa pero no sé que dirección ingresar para que encuentre la base de datos de PC #1 que vendría siendo el servidor. Mi conexion a la base en java es simple con el conector. La red es local desde el mismo internet en la misma red

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basedatos1";
public static final String USERNAME = "root";
public static final String PASSWORD = "1234";

    public static Connection getConection() {
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        btnclientes.setEnabled(true);
        btnproductos.setEnabled(true);
        btnventas.setEnabled(true);
        btncompras.setEnabled(true);
        btninformes.setEnabled(true);
        jLabel2.setVisible(false);
        btncargar.setEnabled(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR: "+e);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR: "+e, "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return con;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que habilitar el usuario desde Workbench para conexiones exteriores para cualquier IP configurándolo como "%", además conectar desde PC#2 a la IP Privada a la PC Servidor (que sería PC#1), y por último habilitar el puerto correspondiente desde una Regla de Entrada del Firewall o desactivarlo en su defecto

PC#1 (servidor):

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basedatos1";
```

Abrir puerto "3306"

PC#2 (cliente):

```
public static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://ipprivadaservidor:3306/basedatos1";
```